# Select2 - How to insert a bolded headline?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I've looked in all the select2's documentation and could not find how can I insert those bold headlines:

[image]

Can someone provide a complete code example (CSS needed ?) of how to achieve this?

Comment: You use optgroups for this.

Comment: I've tried used optgroups but I can't get the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using the `optgroup` tag.

```
<select style="width:300px">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

You'll need to make sure that you include the Select2 CSS file.  If you do not see the correct font, try setting the body to `Arial`.

http://jsfiddle.net/munr/gept53a2/

Answer (score 1):

The example takes one drop down and runs select2 on each, if you are trying to get the example page working

HTML should look exactly like this

```
 <select style="width:300px" id="source">
               <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
                   <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                   <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
               </optgroup>
               <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
                   <option value="CA">California</option>
                   <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                   <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                   <option value="WA">Washington</option>
               </optgroup>
</select>

       <p>
           <select id="e1" class="populate" style="width:300px"></select>
       </p>
```

js from the example looks like this, notice the function takes the source and puts data using the populate class in the each function

```
<script id="script_e1">

$(function() {
   var opts=$("#source").html(), opts2="<option></option>"+opts;
   $("select.populate").each(function() { var e=$(this); e.html(e.hasClass("placeholder")?opts2:opts); });
   $(".examples article:odd").addClass("zebra");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#e1").select2();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly linking the css file select2.css (Get it here: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.css)

There is a class defined in it for that purpose:

```
.select2-results li.select2-result-with-children > .select2-result-label {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Make sure you are properly linking and it is not being overridden.

Comment: It's is properly linked, but what the html should look like ? can you provide an example ?

Comment: The html shown in example of your question above is perfect, check your  browser console and use inspect element to check whether the css is being properly applied or overriden.

Comment: But the html dose not contain label tag