# How to Bold Headline With .select2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2, ui-select2, select2-rails

How can I add a bold headline (aka `optgroup)` with `select2` using ruby?

```
  <%= @challenge.select(:name, [[], ['optgroup label: Mind'], ['Write a Book'], ['Paint a Picture'], ['optgroup label: Body'], ['Run a 5K'], ['Lose 10 Pounds']]) %>

  $('select').select2({
    placeholder: "Enter Challenge",
    theme: "bootstrap",
    allowClear: false,
    tags: true,
    multiple: false,
  });
```

I'm having a hard time translating the answers offered here to a ruby solution: [Select2 - How to insert a bolded headline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192319/select2-how-to-insert-a-bolded-headline)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `grouped_collection_select`?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Updated with example:

Controller:

```
@collection = [['Mind', ['Write a Book', 'Paint a Picture']], ['Body', ['Run a 5K', 'Lose 10 Pounds']]]
```

View:

```
<%= @challenge.grouped_collection_select(:name, @collection, :last, :first, :to_s, :to_s, include_blank: true) %>
```

Obviously I don't have your exact source code, but this should work.

Comment: The docs for this are so confusing. Can you please help me? How would I list out the challenges in the model? The docs just show relationships between different models. And then I guess I could just call those challenges + the optgroup label via `@challenge.grouped_collection_select(:name)`?